# Personal information or generated information

Tags: forms, input-fields, input, feedback, appointment

*Dear community, I am creating a appointment process for a rental process. Currently I am evaluating whether to show the user their First- + Lastname + E-Mail in step (3) that they have entered in stept (1) or just the automatically generated User ID (KdnNr.) that they can see in their E-Mail and their account.*

## But first, let me run you through the process

[image]

1. User is interested in a appartment, fills out the form, is marked in the system as possible interested client
2. User is sent an E-Mail including:

   - Their entered data
   - Their User ID (KdnNr.)
   - Link to choose an appointment in our booking system
3. User chooses time of appointment
4. User is shown a automatically filled form with their data to check if their data is correct and can modify the data if something is wrong
5. Appointment is booked, user gets success E-Mail

### The Idea

Now, as a responsible company, we love to save unneeded processes to save energy for the enviroment and money for more important stuff. This is why our idea is to sent only the User ID (KdnNr.) and the E-mail to Step (4) instead of their full data.

### Why

Due to legal reasons because the whole process is going through two of our systems (object database, appointment system), which is literally two different programms, (which both are more or less intigrated into our CRM), we have the user to enter their data "twice". In the website to show interest in the appartments. And in the appointment software. We are calling the Users data from the automatically generated link in the email at step 2.

### The question

**Would the user be too confused if only their User ID. (KdnNr.) and E-Mail are shown in Step four? Should we include their First + Lastname + E-Mail, too?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it in your process, my assumption would be that the user is only interested in booking the appointment, not in the number the user is in your system. The e-mail seems to me to be there for email verification only, so a small 'thank you for your interest' and a button to make the appointment would be sufficient for your user.

So to answer your question: in my assumption, no.

But hey, there is always the possibility to setup a user test and see if they get confused. In this case it is very easy to setup a screen flow and show them.

Comment: The E-Mail is basically the bridge between our appartments overview and the appointment system (also ours). But since you answered the question seperately I am just making sure again: You think it wouldn't make them confused if their user ID instead of first&lastname is shown in step 4?

Comment: Ah, I misread the first time, I thought it was about the info in the email. My assumption would be that it is enough for the user to have an appointment connected to their email.

Comment: We are considering showing them their pre-filled user ID and make them enter their E-mail as default and will check in an A/B-testing with the names in 70/30. Will update the question if we are finished (most likely january).

Answer (score -1):

I read the question twice but still there's something strange. The idea of requiring the user to insert their information twice is something against a smooth conversion funnel. You are basically placing an unecessary obstacle on your funnel. Usually if you reach the goal to have your user insert the personal data in your databases, you try to avoid ask this again in order to access your services. Simply put: if you get a 30% of conversion rate on the first form, even if you score a astonishing 99% CR on second form, you are still loosing conversions.

If you have technical contraints, I would rather work with coders to solve this issue. If you have legal constraints (and if you can not solve them redesigning the UX) I would rather use the email as username (since it is univocal)

So your journey could go as follows:
1. user chooses an appointment (first step of your funnel)
2. on the same page, once clicked the appointment, user registers with email
3. the systems register the email+password as new user in db and sends an email with the appointment confirmation

*bonus step: if the user is interested in "being in contact" you can let him/her register without choosing an appointment.

Comment: "Due to legal reasons" ... "we have the user to enter their data 'twice'". It's right in the question. Saying that these are two plattforms of ours that are not connected. That's why we have to ask for the data twice.

Comment: Also, the first step is not the appointment. The first step is marking a interest of the object. Step 3 is booking an appointment, as stated in my initial question

Comment: Also, there is absolutely no word of an "password". Please consider re-reading my question and editing/deleting your answer as it is far off. Thanks for the effort, tho.

Comment: 1. Yes, I got the point. I am saying to consider working to connect the two platform to enhanche the journey. 2. Can you explain this concept with an example? What doyou mean by "making interest of the object"? 3. Ok even better then if your users don't need to remember a password. I just thought users could do multiple accesses to the systems for other appointments

Comment: 1.) This is impossible without re-structuring the whole company (which isn't my job and I am not going to suggest, haha). 2) A person sees a object/appartment which he/she likes. Send his/her data to us to plattform1 (appartments plattform) (required for legal reasons, starting a pre-contract), after the background check is successfull, plattform1 sends a e-mail with a personalized link to plattform2 (appointment plattform). 3.) Yeah, that would be a awesome way, but sadly we are required to start the process over and over again per user requesting an appartment. (cont)

Comment: cont: so if user A requests appartment 1 and appartment 2, he has to request two background checks and two appointments. Every appartment can be from another owner who wants different information and underlies different laws depending on the type of appartment, the location of the appartment, the location of the current owner and the location of the new owner or renting person. This is just me trying to scratch at the surface of this (annoying) forrest of laws.